# Understanding running time for merge sort and quick sort

Tags: algorithm, sorting, big-o, quicksort, mergesort

For both merge sort and quick sort, I'm trying to come up with scenarios where they become worst case. If I'm correct, merge sort's worst case O(nlogn) when everything is sorted. Quick sort's worst case is when the pivot is in the least optimal place, and the array is sorted, so it becomes O(n^2). I was wondering if this was correct first off, so please correct me if not. 
My real question is if the pivot for quick sort is in the middle of an array, what would the array have to look like in order for it to be O(n^2)?

Answer (score 1):

Worst case for quick sort is when the pivot is less than or greater than all of the other values left to be sorted. In this case only 1 item is removed from the remaining values at each level of recursion, and the time complexity ends up O(n^2).

For a basic merge sort, top down or bottom up, the number of moves is always the same. The number of compares depends on the data pattern. When merging two runs of size n each, the worst case number of compares is 2n-1 (when every element but 1 from the two runs is compared, when there's just 1 element remaining, there's nothing to compare to, so it's just copied), the best case is when all of the elements of one run are less than the first element of the other run, in which case the number of compares is n, such as when the data is already sorted or reverse sorted.

Comment: So if the pivot was 5 in an array of [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], since it's in the middle, would the running time be O(n log n) because 5 is neither greater than nor less than all of the other values in the array? Also, if the pivot is still 5, and the array is something like [7,8,9,10,5,11,12,13,14], since the pivot is less than all of the other values, would this be an example of O(n^2) time complexity?

Comment: @Dinoman979 - yes, but for O(n^2) time complexity, the code would have to repeatedly encounter the situation where the middle pivot is less than or greater than the remaining values. If the code chooses the middle value, the pattern would be complex, and would depend if the pivot is included or not included in the sub-arrays passed via recursive calls.

Answer (score 0):

You can emulate quicksort, making sure that each time the pivot is chosen it's consecutively 0, 1, 2, ... to guarantee worst-case performance.

This assumes a usual pivoting algorithm that will swap the pivot value to the start of the array before partitioning the array in place. In this case, since we're picking the pivot to be the smallest remaining item, there'll be no partitioning to do.

Here's the emulation code:

```
class Cell:
    def set(self, v):
        self.v = v

def worst_case_quicksort(xs, i):
    xs = xs[:]
    for i in xrange(len(xs)):
        p = (len(xs) - i) // 2
        xs[i+p].set(i)
        xs[i], xs[i+p] = xs[i+p], xs[i]

xs = [Cell() for _ in xrange(20)]
worst_case_quicksort(xs, 0)
print [x.v for x in xs]
```

The output looks like this:

```
[1, 11, 3, 19, 5, 13, 7, 17, 9, 15, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18]
```